# A payment or a curse

Tags: riddle

> I'm a payment.
>   Or a curse.
>   I'm gold.
>   Or the second corner.

What am I?

**Hints**

> If you give me something in its prime, I will give you all but one back.

Comment: The hint makes me think of the Euler totient function, though I don't think that fits any of the actual clues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer is

> $\phi$

I'm a payment.

> $\phi$ is pronounced "fee" and a fee is a payment.

Or a curse.

> Referring to the archaic word ["fie"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fee-fi-fo-fum) (sometimes how $\phi$ is pronounced) used to express disapproval.

I'm gold.

> $\phi$ is the golden ratio

Or the second corner.

> Usually, in geometry, the second Greek letter used to represent an angle, after $\theta$, is $\phi$.

Hint

> Euler's totient function $\phi$ applied to a prime number $p$ gives $p-1$

Comment: This has to be right, but I've never heard of your answer being pronounced the way you claim in the second clue. Is it just in the UK (where I'm from) where it is different?

Comment: @Scoranio As far as I'm aware, Greek people pronounce it "fee" where there is a prevalence among mathematics teachers in some English speaking countries to pronounce it "fy". There might be somebody else here with better knowledge than me though.

Comment: Here in Canada, I've always heard it pronounced the second way, never the first.

Comment: You are correct! Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Is it a

> Debt?

I'm a payment.

> You repay the debt

Or a curse.

> In the bible a debt is a curse.

I'm gold.

> A debt can be payed in Gold.

Still have to figure out the last line.

Comment: Nope! Good try though.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but Is it a

> Reminder

I'm a payment

> Payment reminder

or a curse.

> Reminded to pay overdue

I'm gold.

> ??

or a second corner

> ??